# How to safely access Core data NSManagedObject attributes from a SwiftUI view using swift concurrency model?

Tags: swift, swiftui, core-data, swift-concurrency

How do I safely access Core data NSManagedObject attributes from SwiftUI view using the swift concurrency model.

My understanding is we need to enclose any access to NSManageObject attributes in `await context.perform {}.` But if I use it anywhere in a view be that in the `body(),` or `init()` or `.task()` modifier I get the following warnings or errors:

for `.task{}` modifier or if within any `Task {}:`

> Passing argument of non-sendable type 'NSManagedObjectContext.ScheduledTaskType' outside of main actor-isolated context may introduce data races
> this happens even if I create a new context solely for this access.

if within `body()` or `init():`

> 'await' in a function that does not support concurrency

but we cant set body or init() to async

an example of the code is something along the lines of:

```
var attributeString: String = ""
let context = PersistentStore.shared.persistentContainer.newBackgroundContext()
await context.perform {
    let backgroundObject = context.objectWithID(objectID)
    attributeString = backgroundObject.attribute!
}
```

Comment: gives same warning/error. ill still need a second line to access the attribute. if I do let attirbuteString = await context.perform { return nsmanagedObject.attribute! } same aswell. btw I have the concurrency compiler flags turned on to see these errors/warnings.

Comment: my guess is that you are likely mixing async await with GCD or completion handlers

Answer (score 1):

Your code isn't complete but something like this should work. Create a function to perform the fetch, this function is also where you create the background context

```
func fetchObject(/* params... */) async -> SomeManagedObject {
    let context = PersistentStore.shared.persistentContainer.newBackgroundContext()
    return await context.perform {
         /* fetch */

         return fetchedObject
    }
}
```

and then in your view you call the function and use it

```
.task {
    let managedObject = await fetchObject(/* params */)
    attributesString = managedObject.attribute
```

Answer (score 1):

The trick is to get the `nsmanagedObject.objectID` before your perform block, then inside perform you just need to find the object again in the background context using that ID. Now you have an object that is safe to access from the background, e.g.

```
let objectID = nsmanagedObject.objectID
var attributeString: String = ""
let context = PersistentStore.shared.persistentContainer.newBackgroundContext()
await context.perform {
    let backgroundObject = context.objectWithID(objectID)
    attributeString = backgroundObject.attribute!
}
```

Comment: you are right that I need to use the object id to refetch the object I neglected to include that in my simplified code for the question, and this works when its outside a view. but when in a swiftui view, the warning/error is on the await context.perform line.

Comment: .task is the place to put async code, works for me